# Trying to reverse text, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

Hopefully this makes sense.
Details in the title.
Let me know if more details are needed.

Code:

```
userinput = input("Line: ")
userlen = len(userinput)
output = userinput
count = 0

print(userinput[-0])

while count != userlen:
  count2 = count - (count + 1)
  output[count] = userinput[count2]
  count = count + 1

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> "test word"[::-1]
'drow tset'
```

This uses [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices).

Comment: Wow thanks, turned all of that into 2 lines.

Comment: @DavisGOODMAN Could you accept this answer by clicking the checkmark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this :

```
userinput = input("line: ")
userlen = len(userinput)
output = []
for index in range (userlen -1, -1, -1) :
    output.append (userinput [index])
print(''.join (output))
```